# What is the field "your_type" in Elasticsearch PUT request?

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana, elastic-stack, elasticsearch-5

I am trying to resolve this error:

> Fielddata is disabled on text fields by default. Set fielddata=true on

and saw one post which suggested me to do this; but I didn't get what is **your_type** endpoint in the given snippet:

```
PUT your_index/_mapping/your_type
```

Comment: Please show your current mapping you get with `GET your_index`

Answer (score 1):

I don't know what version of ElasticSearch you have but as of 7.x the mapping type has been removed.

In your case it could run like this (version > 7.x)

```
PUT my-index-000001/_mapping
{
  "properties": {
     "name-field": {
       "type": "text",
       "fielddata": true
     }
  }
}
```

A little about the mapping type:

> Since the first release of Elasticsearch, each document has been
> stored in a single index and assigned a single mapping type. A mapping
> type was used to represent the type of document or entity being
> indexed, for instance a twitter index might have a user type and a
> tweet type.
>
> Each mapping type could have its own fields, so the user type might
> have a full_name field, a user_name field, and an email field, while
> the tweet type could have a content field, a tweeted_at field and,
> like the user type, a user_name field.

More information here:
https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/6.5/removal-of-types.html#_why_are_mapping_types_being_removed